Can't update a riverpod notifier when I inject a service
Introduction
I'm working with riverpod for state management in my application.
I simply want to update a variable when I call my notifier.
The problem occurs when I inject my service into this notifier.

Code
Here is my simplified page, I have a button which updates the orientation of my map through a mapOrientationNotifier.
I also display the compass orientation in real time through a mapCompassNotifier.
map_page.dart:
class MapPage extends ConsumerWidget {
  const MapPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final mapCompassNotifier = ref.watch(mapCompassNotifierProvider);
    final mapOrientationNotifier = ref.watch(mapOrientationNotifierProvider);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        title: mapCompassNotifier.compass != null
          ? Text('Direction: ${mapCompassNotifier.compass!.degree!.toStringAsFixed(2)}°')
          : const Text('Direction: 0°'),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: [
          FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: (){ 
              print("Button pressed. Current mapOrientationState: ${mapOrientationNotifier.mapOrientationState}"); // Debug print
              mapOrientationNotifier.updateMapOrientationState();
             },
            child: mapOrientationNotifier.mapOrientationState == MapOrientationState.north
              ? const Icon(Icons.navigation)
              : const Icon(Icons.assistant_navigation),
          ),       
        ],
      ),
      body: FlutterMap(
        ... some code
      ),
    );
  }
}

Well now let's update the mapOrientationState variable through the updateMapOrientationState method in my mapOrientationNotifier.
map_orientation_notifier.dart:
final mapOrientationNotifierProvider = ChangeNotifierProvider((ref) {
  return MapOrientationNotifierProvider(
    mapController: ref.watch(mapControllerProvider),
  );
});

class MapOrientationNotifierProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  final MapController mapController;

  MapOrientationState mapOrientationState = MapOrientationState.north;
  bool _isDisposed = false;

  MapOrientationNotifierProvider({
    required this.mapController,
  });

  void updateMapOrientationState() {
    if (_isDisposed) return;

    if (mapOrientationState == MapOrientationState.north) {
      mapOrientationState = MapOrientationState.heading;
    } else if (mapOrientationState == MapOrientationState.heading) {
      mapOrientationState = MapOrientationState.north;
      mapController.rotate(0);
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _isDisposed = true;
    super.dispose();
  }
}

It works no problem.
Now I would like to inject a compass Service which I use to retrieve the orientation of the compass in real time.
My compassService works since I can display the value in the appBar in map_page.dart through the compassNotifier.
compass_service.dart:
final compassServiceProvider = ChangeNotifierProvider<CompassService>((ref) {
  return CompassService(
    getCompassUseCase: ref.watch(getCompassUseCaseProvider),
  );
});

class CompassService with ChangeNotifier {
  final GetCompassUseCase getCompassUseCase;

  CompassService({
    required this.getCompassUseCase,
  }){
    _subscribeToCompass();
  }

  StreamSubscription<ResultEntity<CompassEntity?, AppException>>? _compassSubscription;
  CompassEntity? _compass;
  CompassEntity? get compass => _compass;

  void _subscribeToCompass() {
    _compassSubscription = getCompassUseCase.execute().listen(
      (result) {
        result.toResult(
          success: (compass) {
            _compass = compass;
            notifyListeners();
          },
          failure: (_) {
            _compass = null;
            notifyListeners();
          },
        );
      },
      onError: (error) {
        _compass = null;
        notifyListeners();
      }
    );
  }
  
  @override
  void dispose() {
     _compassSubscription?.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
}

map_compass_notifier.dart:
final mapCompassNotifierProvider = ChangeNotifierProvider((ref) { 
  return MapCompassNotifierProvider(
    compassService: ref.watch(compassServiceProvider),
  );
});

class MapCompassNotifierProvider extends ChangeNotifier{
  final CompassService  compassService;

  MapCompassNotifierProvider({
    required this.compassService,
  }){
    _initialize();
  }

  CompassEntity? get compass => compassService.compass;

  LocationMarkerHeading? get userHeading => compassService.compass != null 
    ? UserMarkerHelper.convertToLocationMarkerHeading(compass: compassService.compass!)
    : null;

  void _initialize() {
    compassService.addListener(_updateCompass);
  }

  void _updateCompass() {
    notifyListeners();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    compassService.removeListener(_updateCompass);
    super.dispose();
  }
}


Code with service not works
Now that all this is in place I want to be able to inject my compass service into the mapOrientationNotifier so that I can use the compass value to rotate my map when I change the orientation with mapOrientationState.
Let's take my mapOrientationNotifier and inject the service:
map_orientation_notifier.dart:
final mapOrientationNotifierProvider = ChangeNotifierProvider((ref) {
  return MapOrientationNotifierProvider(
    mapController: ref.watch(mapControllerProvider),
    compassService: ref.watch(compassServiceProvider), // => Add this line
  );
});

class MapOrientationNotifierProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  final MapController mapController;
  final CompassService compassService; // => Add this line

  MapOrientationState mapOrientationState = MapOrientationState.north;
  bool _isDisposed = false;

  MapOrientationNotifierProvider({
    required this.mapController,
    required this.compassService, // => Add this line
  }) {
    compassService.addListener(_onCompassChanged); // => Add this line
  }

  // => Add this method
  void _onCompassChanged() {
    if (_isDisposed) return;

    if (mapOrientationState == MapOrientationState.heading) {
      if (compassService.compass?.degree != null) {
        //mapController.rotate(compassService.compass!.degree!);
      }
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void updateMapOrientationState() {
    if (_isDisposed) return;

    if (mapOrientationState == MapOrientationState.north) {
      mapOrientationState = MapOrientationState.heading;
    } else if (mapOrientationState == MapOrientationState.heading) {
      mapOrientationState = MapOrientationState.north;
      //mapController.rotate(0);
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _isDisposed = true;
    compassService.removeListener(_onCompassChanged); // => Add this line
    super.dispose();
  }
}


Problem
So I just injected the service but the mapOrientationState variable is no longer updated, I don't understand...

It's my first time seeing CompassService with ChangeNotifier extending the notifier with with. And rather then using addListener use ref.listen method to listen to changes.

This does not solve my problem. If you have a better way of doing things I'm interested ;)

I noticed you are not calling updateMapOrientationState() any where inside the _onCompassChanged fn. Meaning even if the compass changes the update fn is not called

I don't need to use updateMapOrientationState() in _onCompassChanged. I'm just looking to update my mapOrientationState variable every time I trigger the updateMapOrientationState() method.
Which works without the service but which no longer works as soon as I inject the service.
